# how to hide sticker/gif suggestions from keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is there any way to hide sticker/gif suggestions from all types of keyboards(including 3rd party)? 
I am able to do that only for Gboard by setting inputType of EditText to InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD.

Any help or suggestion will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I sadly didn't figure out how to hide it on all keyboards. But I found another way. I posted my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72488038/10030894) on a similar question.
I just "block" the user when he tries to import a gif or a stickers whatever the keyboard.