# Android EditText text control - how to disable possibility to insert GIF from Google Keyboard?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext, keyboard, gif

My app's target API is 27 (Oreo). My app uses EditText control for text input. However, from Google Keyboard it's now possible to insert GIF. In this case, my app receives ACTION_SEND intent, with gif inserted from a keyboard, which is implemented for completely different functionality. So it just messes entire app flow and takes the user to completely different activity.

I want my EditText to accept text only and don't allow users to insert any gif there. How can I configure EditText to stop allow inserting GIFS from keyboard?

Comment: Do you have any solutions yet?

Comment: No, still no solution found

Answer (score 6):

**Tested on Samsung Galaxy S9+ (Samsung Keyboard), android 9 and Meizu Pro6 GBoard, android 6. Works perfect**

To fix on GBoard, create your own edit text and override method "onCreateInputConnection(...)" as lines below:

```
    public class NoGifEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo editorInfo) {
        final InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo);
        EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(editorInfo, new String[]{"image/*", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/jpeg"});

        return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, editorInfo,
                (inputContentInfo, flags, opts) -> {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No gif support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                });
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**
Input compat handle insertion of selected mimetypes ("image/*", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/jpeg") and generate event. You catch this event inside block below and just show message, that gif not supported.

```
    {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No gif support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
```

To fix on Samsung keyboard, just add this lines in your edit XML

> android:privateImeOptions="disableSticker=true;disableGifKeyboard=true"

As you see, button "add gif" on Samsung keyboard disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For EditText set the below option.

```
android:privateImeOptions="disableSticker=true;disableGifKeyboard=true"
```

Example :

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
android:privateImeOptions="disableSticker=true;disableGifKeyboard=true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following tricks:

```
view.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT)
```

Set these flags to your view and Gboard hides `GIF` button.

Answer (score 0):

In the Activity that receives intent with action `ACTION_SEND`, add this in `onCreate()`

```
 if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "GIF is not allowed here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
```

So, when app is already open, isTaskRoot() returns false and Activity will be closed and app will be resumed from where it is left.

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix same issue on my app. I created `ArbiterEditText` on which I can set excluded mime types. It works for all android versions.

```kotlin
class ArbiterEditText @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = androidx.appcompat.R.attr.editTextStyle
) : AppCompatEditText(context, attrs, defStyleAttr),
    OnReceiveContentListener {

    var excludedMimeTypes = arrayOf<String>()
        set(value) {
            field = value.toSet().toTypedArray()
            ViewCompat.setOnReceiveContentListener(this, field, this)
        }

    override fun onReceiveContent(view: View, payload: ContentInfoCompat): ContentInfoCompat? {
        val (uriContent, remaining) = payload.partition { it.uri != null }
        if (uriContent != null) {
            val clip: ClipData = uriContent.clip
            (0 until clip.itemCount).forEach { i ->
                val uri: Uri = clip.getItemAt(i).uri
                val mimeType = view.context.contentResolver.getType(uri)
                Toast.makeText(view.context, "$mimeType not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        return remaining
    }

}
```

In the UI layer I just need to set excluded mime types :

```kotlin
arbiterEditTextView.excludedMimeTypes = arrayOf("image/*", "video/*")
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/OnReceiveContentListener) is the doc for `onReceiveContent`.