# Xamarin.forms, on Android, Entry doesn't allow GIF to be inserted but it fills it with the link

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a custom Entry that takes text as input, I've noticed that if I go on the GIF keybord on my Xiaomi, when adding a GIF a Toast comes out saying "GIF are not supported in this text box" but it stills put the link to the GIF in the Entry. This does not happen in other phone but I still want to figure out why, or maybe a way to disable the GIF button.

When approacing to this problem I have tried different solution to disable the GIF keyboard such as [this](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/640594) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54988357/11511759) but they does not seems to work in my case.

Tried to implement this method like reported in the documentation but, in debug mode, it seems it does not even call it

```
public override IInputConnection OnCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs)
        {
            IInputConnection ic = base.OnCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
            EditorInfoCompat.SetContentMimeTypes(outAttrs, new string[] { "image/*", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/jpeg" });

            return InputConnectionCompat.CreateWrapper(ic, outAttrs, null);
        }
```

Tried to add private ImeOptions but nothing

```
Control.PrivateImeOptions = "disableSticker=true;disableGifKeyboard=true";
```

Any idea ?

Comment: If you set the Keyboard property of the entry to "Plain" or "Text"? I don't have the gif on my phone to try it

Comment: @JuanSturla The input type right now is 
`Control.InputType = InputTypes.TextFlagAutoComplete;`
which is android `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE` but also with `Control.InputType = InputTypes.ClassText` which is android `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the emojis with custom renderer.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace App10.Droid
{
public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    public MyEntryRenderer(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.ImeOptions = Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done;
            Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText | Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationVisiblePassword | Android.Text.InputTypes.TextFlagMultiLine;
            Control.SetTypeface(Typeface.Default, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, this does not seems to work on my Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro version 12.5.3.0 Android 10, I still can see the emoji icon which makes me go to the GIF keyboard. I'm now thinking that this could be some OS problem, what do you think ?

Comment: I do not have Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro to test. I tested on Pixel Android 10.